# Site advice: Issue with Ubuntu: "fatal server error, no screens found"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Can anyone please advise on which stack website I should post this question?

> I have an issue with my linux box: the X server won't start and gives me the following error: `fatal server error, no screens found`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If its a ubuntu system, [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [unix and linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). If its any other flavour of linux, SU or UL. I'd suggest giving more details naturally, and to pick one, not post on all three.

Comment: And, balteo: *search* the other sites before posting, please!

Comment: I've spent the best part of yesterday evening searching for a solution...

Comment: Then if you're posting a new question, @balteo, you surely might want to include what you tried (and maybe link to that -- like I see quite some hits when [searching for the error message](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=fatal+server+error%2C+no+screens+found)).

Comment: Exact versions, did it work before (what has changed?), everything up to date, trawl through the logs, ...